# Oracle SQL: Count number of rows with specific value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
ID | AGE 
--------
 1 | 27
 2 | 24
 1 | 25
 4 | 25
 1 | 25
 5 | 25
 5 | 25
...|...
```

As you can see, ID and AGE are not unique (there is a second ID that is unique, but that's irrelevant here).

I want to return all the distinct IDs with more than one specific value: for example, counting all the IDs with more than one AGE = 25; in the table above, this should yield [1, 5], (ID = 4 is not counted because 25 occurs only once; ID = 1 and ID = 5 IS included because 25 occurs more than once in AGE).

Basically what I want in invalid SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table WHERE count(AGE = 25) > 1
```

Unfortunately, count(AGE = 25) is invalid. How would I write this out in SQL?

Comment: You can simply do this in `SQL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
SELECT 
 ID, COUNT(ID)
FROM table
WHERE Age = 25
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
```

Comment: It it possible to count, foreach distinct ID, the number of rows where AGE = 25?

Comment: I changed my answer to what, i think, you want.